# Writing batch file to zip a folder using 7zip

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 7zip

[image: My Folders]

In the image above, I have a batch file in **script** folder that copies all files from **shr02** to **Tempo** using `XCOPY`

**Tempo Folder**

[image: Tempo]
I'm trying to run several trial code to list all directories inside **Tempo** folder Like:

```
SET tmp="C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Tempo\."
FOR /d %%D IN (%tmp%) do echo %%~D
```

However, I am getting confused of getting some folders `.` and `..` and sometimes `File Not Found`

**What I want to accomplish**
I want to compress all the contents of **Tempo** folder using my `7za.exe` (which is inside my **script** folder)
and move it to **Final** folder. How can I achieve this?

**Update**
I tried to run this block of code.

```
SET tmp="C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Tempo"
SET exe="C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\script\7zip\7za.exe"
SET dst="C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Final\tmp.7z"
%exe% "a -t7z %dst% %tmp% -r"
```

Error Message:

> Unsupported Command
>
> a -t7z C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Final\tmp.7z
>   C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Tempo* -r

Comment: The quotes make the whole line appear as a single parameter. You already have quotes around the paths. Don't use them on the command line.

Comment: I have always found it easier to set variables without quotes, then use quotes when the variable is used.  Such as `"%tmp%"`.

Comment: Let me recommend the syntax `set "tmp=C:\Users\Marc\Desktop\Tempo\."`; this is robust against special characters, but the quotes do not become part of the variable value...

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks I got it working now.

Comment: One more thing. Use another variable name instead of `tmp` for your Tempo folder. The variables `tmp` and `temp` have special significance. They define the Windows temporary folder. Many applications, including 7z, use this temporary folder as a miscellaneous work area. By defining your own folder as `tmp` you may get unwanted random temporary work files in there.